# instanceof operator fails when passing an object through windows

Tags: javascript, tabs, window, instanceof, typeof

In order to pass data between windows, I open new windows via the `window.open` method and set a property of the newly opened window to an object. This allows me not only to pass data, but to share the instance of the variable, meaning if I modify the object, or any of its derived properties, on one window, it modifies it on all windows.

The problem, however, is something is going very funny with the instanceof operator.

When I do

```
typeof m
m instanceof Object
```

The first line returns `"object"` while the second one returns `false`.

I specifically need the instanceof operator to check between arrays and objects.

Here is a fiddle of an example (WARNING: tries to open a window on page load, so a popup blocker might block it). http://jsfiddle.net/Chakra/mxf2P/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your window's `Object` and the source window's `Object` aren't the same thing, an instance of one won't be an instance of the other. You can use `Object.prototype.toString` to distinguish between objects and arrays:

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(m) === '[object Array]') {
    // It's an array
} else {
    // It's not
}
```

You can also use `Array.isArray`, if available.

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/mxf2P/2/) (It uses an `<iframe>` instead of a popup, by the way.)

Comment: Thank you so much, isArray works perfectly! Just a question, however: when I change m on the second window, it changes m on the primary window. Is this not the same "instance"? Or do I have my terminology wrong?

Comment: @vox: It's the same instance, but `m` is an instance of the parent's `window.Object` type. When you use `instanceof` in the child, it's using its own `window`'s `Object` type.

Comment: This is lovely! Could you try to replace the child's `window.Object` with a reference to the parent's `window.Object`, and see if `instanceof` works then?