# How to access host element from within the shadow root using Shadow DOM v1?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

Given an element contained in a shadow root, how can I get to the element that hosts the said shadow root? Is there a single way to accomplish this regardless of where an element is in the tree (i.e. given a reference to either `element2` or `element3`, get the reference to `element1`)?

```
element1
└ #shadow-root
  └ element2
    └ element3
```

Comment: Can you include `html`, and the `javascript` that you have tried  at Question?

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Shadow DOM v1, you may use the [`getRootNode()`](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#new-utility-functions-in-node) method.

Then get the `host` attribute:

```
event.target.getRootNode().host
```

Comment: Perfect! I had a hunch it was a built-in; manually walking up the tree was much too cumbersome.

Comment: It looks like this is a dead link. Is there a live piece of documentation for that method?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep iterating [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) until you get the shadow root, and then get [`host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/host).

```
function getHostElement(el) {
  while (el.parentNode) el = el.parentNode;
  return getShadowRoot(el).host;
}
var element1 = document.createElement('element1');
var element2 = document.createElement('element2');
var element3 = document.createElement('element3');
element2.appendChild(element3);
var shadowRoot = element1.createShadowRoot();
shadowRoot.appendChild(element2);
getHostElement(element3); // element1
```