# Identify second/third saturday using moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to implement a method which will return if a date is a holiday or not. For the purpose of this use case, a holiday is naively defined as all sundays, and both second and third saturdays. Here is a snippet of the code,

```
export const isHoliday = (date: moment.Moment | Date) => {
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    date = moment(date);
  }

  const dayOfWeek = date.day();

  if (dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek < 6) {
    // it is a weekday
    return false;
  }

  if (dayOfWeek === 0) {
    // it is a sunday
    return true;
  }

  if (dayOfWeek === 6) {
    return isSecondSaturday(date) || isThirdSaturday(date);
  }
};
```

And here are the other methods,

```
const isSecondSaturday = (date: moment.Moment) => {
  return isNthSaturday(date, 2);
};

const isThirdSaturday = (date: moment.Moment) => {
  return isNthSaturday(date, 3);
};

const isNthSaturday = (today: moment.Moment, n: number) => {
  const thisMonth = today.clone().utc().startOf("month");
  const firstSaturday = thisMonth.day(6); // <-- culprit?
  const nthSaturday = firstSaturday.add(n - 1, "week");

  return nthSaturday.date() === today.date();
};
```

In my testing, I found that the second and third Saturdays are not correctly identified for certain months. I think it could be something minor that I'm missing.

Comment: Testing with *instanceof* is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391506/instanceof-operator-fails-when-passing-an-object-through-windows?r=SearchResults&s=3|59.0372). Since you're using moment.js already, then use [*isValid*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-a-date/), e.g. `if (moment.isValid(date))...`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) I will do that ❤️

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide for which month the following implementation does not work? I've put your implementation to the console and checked first four months - it works fine.

```js
function isHoliday(date) {
  const dayOfWeek = date.day();

  if (date instanceof Date) {
    date = moment(date);
  }


  if (dayOfWeek >= 1 && dayOfWeek < 6) {
    // it is a weekday
    return false;
  }

  if (dayOfWeek === 0) {
    // it is a sunday
    return true;
  }

  if (dayOfWeek === 6) {
    return isSecondSaturday(date) || isThirdSaturday(date);
  }
};

function isSecondSaturday(date) {
  return isNthSaturday(date, 2);
};

function isThirdSaturday(date) {
  return isNthSaturday(date, 3);
};

function isNthSaturday(today, n){
  const thisMonth = today.clone().utc().startOf("month");
  const firstSaturday = thisMonth.day(6); // <-- culprit?
  const nthSaturday = firstSaturday.add(n - 1, "week");
  return nthSaturday.date() === today.date();
};



function checkHolidaysInMonth(monthIndex) {
  var thisYear = moment().utc().startOf("year");
  thisYear.add(monthIndex,'months');
  for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
    if(isHoliday(thisYear) === true) {
      console.log("Is 2nd or 3rd Sat or Sun: " + thisYear.format())
    }
    thisYear.add(1,'days');
  }
}

checkHolidaysInMonth(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Marek for helping out. I was doing some more debugging, and I think you are right. I think there was a side effect in one of the other methods (which I hadn't shared since I felt it was not relevant to the problem). I used clone() on all arguments passed in, and now it is working! 

Please let me know if you think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured out the solution. I had been using another method in my code which would find the last working date. This involved some subtraction of date. This should have been isolated to the method, but **since momentjs mutates the original moment, it caused a side effect** whenever that function was called.

So if ever you are manipulating an argument, please use the `clone()` method ([see docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/)) on it before you do the operation.

e.g. `moment().clone()`